# Is it possible to store simple data (such as string/int/double) into Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have this class called CardModel that acts like a container and stores the cardName (as string), a caption (string), gps coordinates (double), and a few other things. I want to be able to store a cardModel object into Firebase. But it seems Firebase storage only deals with Files/URI/ and anything to do with photos or videos. Must I use the Firebase real time database to store my customized objects? And can Firebase database be the only one to store simple data types such as strings, doubles, and ints?

Hope you guys can help.

Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database is the perfect tool for storing this data. To help you navigate the differences, I've included a handy guide that covers what each product does.

The best place to store your data, depends on the type of data you want to store and the way you want to consume it.

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/#implementation_path) says this about each product:

> - The Firebase Realtime Database stores JSON application data, like game state or chat messages, and synchronizes changes instantly across all connected devices.
> - Firebase Remote Config stores developer-specified key-value pairs to change the behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to download an update.
> - Firebase Hosting hosts the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for your website as well as other developer-provided assets like graphics, fonts, and icons.
> - Firebase Storage stores files such as images, videos, and audio as well as other user-generated content.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mike!