# Android app uses a lot of data when retrieving images from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an issue with retrieving data from my database. 
When I open the application, the application will get data from the firebase in `onCreate()` and add this to the recycler view. 
The data is structured like this:

```
"Items" {
    "some category" {
         "useruid" {
             "some key" {
                  "Title" : "Some time",
                  "Info" : "Some info about the item",
                  "photoitem" : "A image that is compressed / encoded to a base 64 string"
                  "useruid" : "the user uid, which i use for something else" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, at the time I'm testing, I have 3 items ("some keys"). When I am retrieving the data, I can see in the Android Profiler that the application uses 16mb of data to retrieve these three items, which is way too much. Does applications use this much data when retrieving images, or am I doing something wrong?

NB: The structure in the database makes it easy to get items from different categories, and only show items that the user does have / does not have.

Any tip/help would be really helpful. Since 26.11 untill today, my application has used 9,4gb of data by only testing (opening the app, then closing etc.).

This is how I save the images to the firebase:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    //Dersom startActivityForResult er velykket, kjøres denne
    Log.d(TAG, " Før requestCode check");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        Log.d(TAG, " Før resultCode check");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Setter bildet i imageviewet og sender det til firebasedatabasen
            //setPic();
            //Lagrer bildet i galleriet
            galleryAddPic();

            Log.d(TAG, " Bilde lagt til i galleri");

            try {
                handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(getApplicationContext(), photoURI);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {Log.d(TAG, "Fungerte ikke");}
        }
    }

}

    //Gjør om bildet til base64 (en String), slik at det kan legges til i databasen som en string

    public void addImageToFirebase(Bitmap bitmap) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d(TAG, "Image added to firebase");
        try {
            baos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());

        }


    }

    public void handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage)
            throws IOException {
        int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
        int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
        imageStream.close();

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

        img = rotateImageIfRequired(context, img, selectedImage);

        //Legger bildet til i databasen
        //Legger bildet til i imageviewet
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userImageInput);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(img);
        addImageToFirebase(img);

    }

    private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 2;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee a final image
            // with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

            final float totalPixels = width * height;

            // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
            final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

            while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                inSampleSize++;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context, Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    ExifInterface ei;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
        ei = new ExifInterface(input);
    else
        ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());

    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return rotateImage(img, 90);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return rotateImage(img, 180);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return rotateImage(img, 270);
        default:
            return img;
    }
}
```

And this is how the image-string gets decoded:

```
//Retrieving from firebase:
private void prepareItemData() {
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbref = database.getReference("Items");

    dbref.child("category").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if(!dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(thisUser)) {
                        Items item1 = ds.getValue(Items.class);
                        lowagedata.add(item1);
                    }
                }
                iAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

//Here is the decoder: 

public static Bitmap decodeFromFirebaseBase64(String image) throws IOException {
    byte[] decodedByteArray = android.util.Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByteArray, 0, decodedByteArray.length);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to upload 100% quality images in full resolution?

Comment: No, i have been trying to play around with the quality, but i think it is the resoulation that might be the problem. Tried some different scale / shrink methods, but i cant find anything to works the way i want it too. With 50% quality, each image still takes 3-4 mb to upload from the database.

Comment: How large are the image files on disk already?

Comment: The image files in "gallery" on the phone is the same size as the data that gets sent to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't store images in the Firebase Database**. There is absolutely no reason to do so, and this alone inflates your memory usage (due to having the data in memory and requiring base64 encoding).

Instead store your images in [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). This had the advantage that you can [upload them straight from the device disk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files), [download them straight to the device disk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_to_a_local_file), and that you don't need to base64 encode the data.

Also see these questions about where in Firebase to store what type of data:

- [Is it possible to store simple data (such as string/int/double) into Firebase storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388305/is-it-possible-to-store-simple-data-such-as-string-int-double-into-firebase-st)
- [Firebase : Differences between realtime database and file storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482907/firebase-differences-between-realtime-database-and-file-storage)

Comment: Ah, okay. Guess i will have to rewrite alot then. Thanks Frank! Hope this helps with the data usage problem.